# onclick auto executing in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm having a little trouble with my python/django web app. I'm trying to be able to enable and disable something in the admin area so that in the front end will either show it or not.

Once the link is clicked I want the function called updatevisibilitymain to execute with passing in the main.id. The issue is it auto fires on page loads along with if you click one link all three fire and update each main item respectively according to the main.id. I only want one link to fire at a time along with not having it auto fire on a page load.

My issue is my  link.

```
<a href="" id="{{main.id}}" onclick="{% updatevisiblitymain main.id %}" class="toggler"><i class="{% isvisible main.is_visible %}" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

When I load the page the onclick its auto called and disables and or enables every page load. On top of that I have two more links for that are similar as they are created in a for loop. And if I click any of the three they all will execute and either disable or enable the object. Any one have any ideas on how to fix this?

I've tried putting a # inside the href area and then the onclick function does not work when clicked.

EDIT: updatevisibilitymain

```
@register.simple_tag
def updatevisiblitymain(cid):
""" Updates the visibility of the main category """
print cid

main = MainCategory.objects.get(pk=cid)
visible = main.is_visible
if visible:
    main.is_visible = False
    main.save()
    logger.debug('Main Category %s has been marked false.' % main.name)
else:
    main.is_visible = True
    main.save()
    logger.debug('Main Category %s has been marked true.' % main.name)
```

django template

```
<div class="row">
                {% if sub_cats %}
                    {% for sub in sub_cats %}
                        {% if sub.main_category_id == main_id %}
                            <div class="pull-left pad-10">
                                {% for main in main_cats %}
                                    {% if main.id == main_id %}
                                        <a href="" id="{{main.id}}" onclick="{% updatevisiblitymain main.id %}" class="toggler"><i class="{% isvisible main.is_visible %}" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                        <span class="form-section">{{ main.name }}</span>
                                        <a href=""  class="gutter"><i class="{% helptext main.help_text %}" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                        <a href="/MFA/DeleteItem/maincat/{{main.id}}" class="gutter"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash-o red" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
              </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is you're trying to do.  Can you edit the question to provide more clarity with respect to the desired output?

Comment: Hope it helps. I'm also adding it here.

Once the link is clicked I want the function called updatevisibilitymain to execute with passing in the main.id. The issue is it auto fires on page loads along with if you click one link all three fire and update each main item respectively according to the main.id

Comment: Can you post the code where `updatevisiblitymain` is defined, and perhaps the rest of your Django template?

Comment: added what I have as of right now.

Answer (score 1):

You have not understood the distinction between front-end and back-end code.

`onclick` is a Javascript event handler. It should contain JS code that executes on the frontend.

Django template language executes on the backend. It is called at render time, when the user first requests the page, not when they interact with it.

The way to do this is to write a JS function that uses Ajax to call a Django view which updates the visible status.

Comment: I thought I was doing it wrong. I'll look into what you suggest. Thanks for the suggestion.